# Running bash script by itself vs within another script yields different variable value

Tags: bash

I currently have 2 bash scripts:

1) tomcat.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    'start')
        /home/testuser/start.sh
        ;;
    'status')
        /home/testuser/status.sh
        ;;
 esac
```

2) status.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT="$( ps -ef | grep tomcat| wc -l )"
echo ${COUNT}
if [ "${COUNT}" -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "Tomcat is running."
else
    echo "Tomcatis not running"
fi
```

When I check status via these two methods:

`./tomcat.sh status`: `${COUNT}` echos a value of `4`.

`status.sh`: `${COUNT}` echos value of `2`.

I'm not sure why there is a discrepancy. I'm expecting both values from `echo` to match since they are essentially executing `status.sh`. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Added in the actual search values I'm using.

Comment: If you use grep to filter ps output, there will be one more process matching - the grep itself. This is the case for "grep appname", which will find a process named appname, and will also find another process "grep appname" :-) -- you could try pidof(1)

Comment: or: `man pgrep`

Comment: Thanks @linuxfan and @Cyrus. Although I'm still confused as to why running it via `./app.sh status ` and `./status.sh` yields a different echo value. Shouldn't both be the same since it's essentially running the script `status.sh`?

Comment: @TimothyT. Maybe; that `ps | grep` pipeline is timing-dependent, so it can vary unpredictably based on apparently irrelevant things. But that should only add one to the match count, not two. Does the name of the outer script ("app.sh") match the app name as well?

Comment: Hello @GordonDavisson, yup the name of the outer script ("app.sh") matches the grep value I'm searching for ("app"). Although I've since renamed it to some random value ("abc.sh"), and re-tested -- still getting a different echo value for both.

Comment: Try either using `pgrep` (which exists specifically to avoid this problem) or using a pattern for the app name that doesn't match itself (the standard trick is to put square brackets around one character in the name, e.g. `grep "[a]ppname"`). Either of those should give you saner results. If not, you'll have to try capturing the output rather than just counting lines, and see what processes are being found.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson, I found the source of the error. I followed your advice to echo out the processes and debugged from there. Turns out the outer script will also have a process matching its name, causing the grep results to show additional processes. I fixed it by changing the filter to use pgrep. Would you like to post your answer below so that I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tomcat.sh` is still running when the `ps -ef` in `status.sh` is running. So, in case of using `tomcat.sh` ps finds at least these:

- tomcat.sh
- the tomcat you are looking for
- grep tomcat (if you pipe, processes are started right to left, so when ps is running, your grep is also already running)

Right now I am not sure where the 4th is coming from.

In case of just running the status script, it is not finding tomcat.sh and thus you have less results. A solution could be to make your grep more specific for your use case, or use something that is more specific for your task, like pgrep (although `pgrep java` will possibly also give you other unwanted processes).

Possible solution:

```
COUNT="$( ps -ef | grep "tomcat" | grep "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" | wc -l )"
```

Edit: Using a pidfile is of course also a way of doing it. In the question you show something that looks like a startup script. So writing a pidfile when starting and then reading and using that pidfile when querying, you can know if the service is started. It won't work though if someone uses another way to start the service.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a slightly different formula which works as well. I appreciate the explanation as to why the `ps -ef` command is returning more if i use `tomcat.sh`